# Is there a way to view native PHP classes with all their methods and properties?

Tags: php, class, oop

Is there a way to view all the methods and properties of classes that are already available in PHP? Included classes that come with PHP extensions like mysqli or PDO? Are they actually somewhere readable as PHP code or are they written in the same language PHP is written in?

Comment: https://github.com/php/php-src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is written in C. Some of the PHP functions are methods that were written for the language, while others work as a kind of wrapper, e.i. PHP passes the call to another library.

As Manh already commented, the source code is available at [github](http://github.com/php/php-src), but it is not very easy to read, and contains much more than just the methods and classes that are directly available in the PHP language.

I'd rather look at the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/), specifically the section called [Function Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/funcref.php). There might be other resources out there, but these are the official ones.

Comment: Thank you very much that's really helpful. What I'm especially interested in are the magic methods like __destruct(), but I think that's even harder to find out?

Comment: @SamuelMo That depends on just what you'd like to find out. These methods are implemented as complex C code that deals with memory management, counter references and more.

Comment: @SamuelMo The implementation of __destruct is, as far as I can decipher from the C code, in this chunk: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/d6c332eb513371bc7fc6b8b53016b50c73aad158/Zend/zend_objects.c#L87-L167